# How to affect kernel request hostname when bootstrapping from custom PHP script

Tags: 8, bootstrapping

I'm bootstraping from a custom PHP script using:

```
$autoloader = require_once 'web/autoload.php';
$request = Request::create('/');
// $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = 'whatever';
// $request->server->set('SERVER_NAME', 'whatever');
$this->kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod');
$this->kernel->boot();
$this->kernel->prepareLegacyRequest($request);
```

When rendering a URL from that bootstrapped Drupal, via `$item->link->getUrlObject()->toString()`, it has a `localhost` hostname:

```
http://localhost/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/images/pages/1.JPG?itok=gSuAsMq-
```

I want to change that to `whatever` and I've tried what is commented out in the initial block which doesn't work. I've confirmed that the `$request->server->set(..., ...);` does set the value though.

Any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `HTTP_HOST` instead the `SERVER_NAME`, also you can pass it as `$server` param to the `Request::create()`

```php
$autoloader = require_once 'web/autoload.php';
$request = Request::create('/', 'GET', [], [], [], ["HTTP_HOST" => 'whatever']);
$this->kernel = DrupalKernel::createFromRequest($request, $autoloader, 'prod');
$this->kernel->boot();
$this->kernel->prepareLegacyRequest($request);
```

Remember to add the hostname to `$settings['trusted_host_patterns']`